# Not sure how to enter the output from one function as the input for another

Tags: python

I have a script here with some basic funtions:
Function 1 - wget, opens a webpage and saves it to a local variable then closes.
Function 2 - scrapes this webpage for md5 hash values.
Function 3 - takes the hash values and cracks them using a dictionary of commonly used passwords.

My problem is getting my output from Function 2 and inserting it into Function 3. This is partly due to the output from Function 2 being a list and Function 3 is looking for just hash values.

You guys will most likely be able to understand more from reading my code, below is my code so far.

```
import sys, hashlib, re, urllib

def wget(url): # could import webpage_get and use wget() from there instead
    '''Read the contents of a webpage from a specified URL'''
    print '[+]---------------------------------------------------------------------------- ' #CHANGE THIS
    # open URL
    webpage = urllib.urlopen(url)  # opens url like a file
    # get page contents
    page_contents = webpage.read()  # reads content of webpage
    return page_contents
    page_contents = webpage.close() # close webpage

def findmd5(text):
    '''Find all md5 hash values'''
    md5value = re.findall(r'([a-fA-F\d]{32})', text)
    count = len(md5value)
    print  "[+] Total number of md5 hash values found: %s" % count
    for x in md5value:
        print x


def dict_attack(passwd_hash):

    dic = ['123','1234','12345','123456','1234567','12345678','password','qwerty','abc','abcd','abc123','111111','monkey','arsenal','letmein','trustno1','dragon','baseball','superman','iloveyou','starwars','montypython','cheese','123123','football','password','batman']


    passwd_found = False
    for value in dic:
        hashvalue = hashlib.md5(value).hexdigest()
        if hashvalue == passwd_hash:
            passwd_found = True
            recovered_password = value

    if passwd_found == True:
        print '[+] Password recovered: %s'% (recovered_password)
    else:
        print '[-] Password not recovered'


def main():
    # temp testing url argument
    sys.argv.append('URL HERE!')

    # Check args
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print '[-] Usage: email_analysis URL/filename'
        return
    #call functions
    try:
        print '[+] md5 values found: '
        print findmd5(wget(sys.argv[1]))
        print '[+] Cracking hash values: '


    except IOError:
        print 'Error'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I saw a question about this exact same assignment less than an hour ago. Can you work with your classmate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wget: Set return statement as last statement.

findmd5: Changed from printing it's results, to returning them to a variable in main.

main: added in for loop to iterate over found hashes and apply dict_attack to each value.

I did however not build in any break or stop condition, so even if found, the program will continue running. It will however still print the found result.

```
import sys, hashlib, re, urllib

def wget(url): # could import webpage_get and use wget() from there instead
    '''Read the contents of a webpage from a specified URL'''
    print ('[+]---------------------------------------------------------------------------- ') #CHANGE THIS
    # open URL
    webpage = urllib.urlopen(url)  # opens url like a file
    # get page contents
    page_contents = webpage.read()  # reads content of webpage
    page_contents = webpage.close() # close webpage
    return page_contents

def findmd5(text):
    '''Find all md5 hash values'''
    md5value = re.findall(r'([a-fA-F\d]{32})', text)
    count = len(md5value)
    print  ("[+] Total number of md5 hash values found: %s" % count)
    return md5value


def dict_attack(passwd_hash):

    dic = ['123','1234','12345','123456','1234567','12345678','password','qwerty','abc','abcd','abc123','111111','monkey','arsenal','letmein','trustno1','dragon','baseball','superman','iloveyou','starwars','montypython','cheese','123123','football','password','batman']


    passwd_found = False
    for value in dic:
        hashvalue = hashlib.md5(value).hexdigest()
        if hashvalue == passwd_hash:
            passwd_found = True
            recovered_password = value

    if passwd_found == True:
        print ('[+] Password recovered: %s'% (recovered_password))
    else:
        print ('[-] Password not recovered')


def main():
    # temp testing url argument
    sys.argv.append('URL HERE!')

    # Check args
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print ('[-] Usage: email_analysis URL/filename')
        return
    #call functions
    try:
        md5Values = findmd5(wget(sys.argv[1]))
        for md5value in md5values:
            dict_attack(md5value)
            print ('[+] Cracking hash values: ')


    except IOError:
        print ('Error')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!!

Answer (score 0):

Billy, return a a list of the hashes found, instead of printing them (it looks like you are thinking like it was bash, but you don't need to "print" the output of a function, as you did in bash, in python you can literally return an array with the elements found).

Your regexp for the hash uses `\d`, but that includes `-` as well, it might bring something that is not a MD5 hash.